# Google のサービスで許可した OAuth を削除する方法

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

AndroidのアプリとGoogle App Engineの中でOAuth2を使用してGoogleアカウント名
を得る処理があり、以前(少なくとも2015/2月頃まで)は初めてAndroidアプリを
起動するユーザーに対して許可を求めるconsent screen(許可画面?)が表示されていたの
ですが、先日試した所consent screenが出ることなくGoogleアカウントの一部情報への
アクセスが許可されるようになりました。

上記Googleアカウントの一部情報を得る処理とはAndroidアプリの中で
Google APIs Client for Java の
GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience()
を呼び出す処理のことです。

そこで質問なのですが、
1) この数ヶ月の間にGoogleの方針変更などにより、ユーザーの許可を得る必要
(consent screenを表示する必要)が無くなったのでしょうか？
もしそうである場合、それに関する説明がなされたURLも教えていただけると嬉しいです。

2) 以前はユーザーが与えた許可を以下のlinkから取り消すことが出来たのですが、
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
今は私のアプリは一覧に表示されなくなりました。
(初回起動時の動作をテストするために特に重要です)

また、上記linkに表示される項目が減ったように感じており、例えば以前はIngressなども
表示されていたのですが、現在は表示されておりません。

この辺り 1) の質問とも関連しますが、自分のアプリの許可を削除するには
どうすればよいのでしょうか？
またこの辺りの事情を説明したURLをご存知であればお教え下さい。